# How to add event in fullcalendar using asp.net

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, tooltip

I'm trying to create a function for adding events by button in my asp.net core MVC app:

Index.cshtml:

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
            initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
            nowIndicator: true,
            headerToolbar: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'addEventButton',
                right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
            },
            navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
            editable: true,
            selectable: true,
            selectMirror: true,
            dayMaxEvents: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            
            eventClick: function (arg) {
                if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this event?')) {
                    arg.event.remove()
                }
            },

            events: '/Home/GetEvents',
            
            eventDidMount: function (info) {
                $(info.el).tooltip({
                    title: info.event.extendedProps.description,
                    container: 'body',
                    delay: { "show": 50, "hide": 50 }
                });
            },
            
            customButtons: {
                addEventButton: {
                    text: 'add event...',
                    click: function () {
                        var dateStr = prompt('Enter a date in YYYY-MM-DD format');
                        var date = new Date(dateStr + 'T00:00:00'); // will be in local time

                        if (!isNaN(date.valueOf())) { // valid?
                            calendar.addEvent({
                                title: 'dynamic title',
                                start: date,
                                allDay: true
                            });
                            alert('Great. Now, update your database...');
                        } else {
                            alert('Invalid date.');
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        calendar.render();
    });
</script>

<div id='calendar'></div>
```

and the newly created event is displayed in my fullcalendar, but after this i cant do anything: delete events, add new and others (no changes in my calendar)

**a new event that was added via a button**

[image: a new event that was added via a button]

and i have a error:

```
index.global.js:9 Uncaught TypeError: TOOLTIP: Option "title" provided type "undefined" but expected type "(string|element|function)".
    at bootstrap.bundle.min.js:6:1021
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at r (bootstrap.bundle.min.js:6:856)
    at Ye._getConfig (bootstrap.bundle.min.js:6:68366)
    at new Ye (bootstrap.bundle.min.js:6:60740)
    at Ye.getOrCreateInstance (bootstrap.bundle.min.js:6:6735)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (bootstrap.bundle.min.js:6:69178)
    at Function.each (jquery.js:381:19)
    at jQuery.fn.init.each (jquery.js:203:17)
    at jQuery.fn.init.jQueryInterface [as tooltip] (bootstrap.bundle.min.js:6:69150)
```

can you help me to solve it? i think i have problem in my libraries, but i cant understand what exactly is the problem

libraries that i use:

Layout.cshtml

```
<body>
<script src='~/fullcalendar/dist/index.global.js'></script> //fullcalendar6-1-9
<script src='~/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js'></script> // bootstrap@5.1.1
<script src='~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js'></script> //jQuery JavaScript Library v3.5.1
</body>
```

in function "addEvent" i tried to convert title parameter to a String, but it doesnt help

```
calendar.addEvent({
                                title: "new event",
                                start: date,
                                allDay: true
                            });
```

Comment: The error seems to come from the Tooltip tool. So I'd guess `title: info.event.extendedProps.description` is the offending line. Probably, one or more of your fullCalendar event objects doesn't have a `description` (hence the report of the title value being "undefined" - when it's supposed to be a string, element or function).

Comment: Certainly when you're running `calendar.addEvent` you aren't providing a description for those events, so that's probably the root cause of the issue. What did you expect the tooltip to display, when you don't specify a description??

Comment: ok i understood, when i load events from database, description without any content convert from null to just "" and because of this i did not get this error, I led astray by this, I'll be more careful, thank you so much